# Column count check for csv before the csv is loaded in multiple worksheets using macro

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have an workbook with 3 worksheets.I want to load the a single sectionedwise csv to the multiple worksheets but before loading the csv I need to do the column count check to ensure that correct csv is loaded.

the csv will be as follows :

```
#3GMACRO,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
    IMSI,IMEI,Date,Time,UMTS MACRO-PARAMNAME,UMTS MACRO-UARFCNDL,UMTS MACRO-                             PrimaryScramblingCode,UMTS MACRO-CPICHTxPower,UMTS MACRO-PLMNCellId,UMTS MACRO- RNCId,UMTS MACRO-MCC,UMTS MACRO-MNC,UMTS MACRO - LAC,UMTS MACRO - RAC,UMTS MACRO - MaxUETxPower,UMTS MACRO - MeasuredRSCP
    208101386528204,357539010035240,20100107,160000,macro1_param,10662,11,-99,268435456,0,0,1,1,0,0,-74
#3GFEMTO,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
IMSI,IMEI,Date,Time,UMTS FEMTOS-PARAMNAME,UMTS FEMTOS-UARFCNDL,UMTS FEMTOS-  PrimaryScramblingCode,UMTS FEMTOS-CPICHTxPower,UMTS FEMTOS-PLMNCellId,UMTS FEMTOS-RNCId,UMTS FEMTOS-MCC,UMTS FEMTOS-MNC,UMTS FEMTOS-LAC,UMTS FEMTOS-RAC,UMTS FEMTOS-MaxUETxPower,UMTS FEMTOS- MeasuredRSCP
208101386528204,357539010035240,20100107,160000,macro1_param,10687,252,-24,61,0,610,3956,486,11,5,-102
#2GMACRO,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
IMSI,IMEI,Date,Time,GSM MACRO-PARAMNAME,GSM MACRO_CellID,GSM MACRO-MCC,GSM MACRO-MNC,GSM MACRO-LAC,GSM MACRO-RAC,GSM MACRO-Max permitted UE Tx power (SIB3),GSM MACRO-Measure RSSI
208101386528204,357539010035240,20100107,160000,macro1_param,GSM_Cell_Id=1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

The header are IMSI,IMEI,Date,Time......... in each.

what will happen is when the user click the load button it will load this sectioned csv into 3 different worksheets as shown below, but what i want is before loading the csv i should check the column count in all three worksheets each simultaneously before loading the csv in each sheets.This is needed because if the column count is done so that the user cannot load the wrong csv file.If he loads the wrong csv file then we can say like invalid csv chosen.I wanted in this concept.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use VBA and ordinary file I/O to inspect the file, but what I'd do is load it into a hidden sheet, verify it, then copy the data from the hidden sheet to the user-visible sheet.

This also gives you an opportunity to reorganize the presentation if that's useful.